# How do I fetch specific bytes from a file knowing the offset and length?

Tags: java, byte, randomaccessfile

I have a file, and the first 4 bytes of the file are the magic such as `LOL` .
How would I be able to get this data?

I imagined it would be like:

```
byte[] magic = new byte[4];
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
raf.read(magic, 0, magic.length);
System.out.println(new String(magic));
```

Output:

`LOL`

Sadly this isn't working for me. I can't find a way to fetch specific values.

Does anyone see any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`RandomAccessFile.seek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek-long-) to position to where you want to read from and [`RandomAccessFile.readFully()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readFully-byte:A-) to read a full `byte` array.

```
byte[] magic = new byte[4];
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
raf.seek(0L);
raf.readFully(magic);
System.out.println(new String(magic));
```

The problem with your code is that when you create the file in read-write mode, most likely the file pointer points to the end of the file. Use the `seek()` method to position.

Also you can use the [`RandomAccessFile.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) method too, but the offset and length corresponds to the offset **in the array** where to start storing the read bytes, and length specifies how many bytes to read from the file. But the data will still be read from the **current position of the file**, not from the `off` position.

So once you called `seek(0L);`, this read method also works:

```
raf.read(magic, 0, magic.length);
```

Also note that the read and write methods will automatically move the current position, so for example seeking to `0L`, then reading 4 bytes (your magic word) will result in the current pointer being moved to `4L`. This means you can call read methods subsequently without having to seek before each read and they will read a continuous portion of the file increasing by position, they will not read from the same position.

**Last Note:**

When creating a `String` from a `byte` array, quoting from the javadoc of [`String(byte[] bytes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-):

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the **platform's default charset**.

So the platform's default charset will be used which may be different on different platforms. Always specify a correct encoding like this:

```
new String(magic, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Works, thanks a lot. I never new that's how the RAF implementation worked. Thanks ;) I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes (stackoverflow limit).