# Read Data File address (Java)

Tags: java, file

I have this code for reading data and works fine but I want to change the start point that the data is read from - My DataFile.txt is "abcdefghi"
and the output is

```
1)97                
2)98                                                                       
3)99                                                                            
4)100
```

I want to start at the second byte so the output would be

```
1)98              
2)99           
3)100  
4)etc
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ReadFileDemo3 {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {     
        MASTER MASTER = new MASTER();
        MASTER.PART1();
    }
}

class MASTER {
    void PART1() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("OK START THIS PROGRAM");
        File file = new File("D://DataFile.txt");
        BufferedInputStream HH = null;
        int B = 0;
        HH = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            B = B + 1;   
            System.out.println(B+")"+HH.read());
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)

Comment: You can also use RandomAcessFile, see this example for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671126/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-certain-offset

Comment: ill also have a look at the

Answer (score 0):

You can simple ignore the first `n` bytes as follows.

```
HH = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
int B = 0;
int n = 1; // number of bytes to ignore

while(HH.available()>0) {
    // read the byte and convert the integer to character
    char c = (char)HH.read();
    if(B<n){
        continue;
    }
    B++;
    System.out.println(B + ")" + (int)c);
}
```

---

**Edit**: If you want to access a random location in file, then you need to use [RandomAccessFile](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_randomaccessfile.htm). See [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.io.RandomAccessFile) for detailed examples.

Related SO post:

- [How do I fetch specific bytes from a file knowing the offset and length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790224/how-do-i-fetch-specific-bytes-from-a-file-knowing-the-offset-and-length)
- [How to read a file from a certain offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671126/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-certain-offset)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but something is not right n doesn't seem to be used :)

Comment: what is that something which is not working? I assumed your code is correct and so modified it little bit as you mentioned - you just want to skip the first byte. note that, i didn't run the code to check if its working!

Comment: Thanks again for your reply I want to go to an exact address/offset ?

Comment: Thank you again Sir ill investigate :)

Comment: I cant get this working                                                                                        
import java.io.File;
     import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class ReadTest {
     
 
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {   
        
   byte[]     magic = new byte[4];
    File file = new File("D://test.map");
raf = new RandomAccessFile(file );
raf.seek(0L);
raf.readFully(magic);
System.out.println(new String(magic));
        
        
        
    }
    }