# Read Data Byte not just Word at offset JAVA

Tags: java, byte, cpu-word

From another question in the link below I'm reading a data file I want to read a data file word not just byte with values above 255, how do I do this? and exact offset if possible

[Read Data File address (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833625/read-data-file-address-java/44833763#44833763)

There were replys to using RandomAcessFile but I cant get it working any help?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class ReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {   

    byte[]     magic = new byte[4];
    File file = new File("D://test.map");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file );
    raf.seek(0L);
    raf.readFully(magic);
    System.out.println(new String(magic));        
    }
}
```

> error line 13 "RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file );"

Comment: What error? Why do you have whitespace after `file`? Is the magic number actually displayable as a `String`?

Comment: You are trying to call a consturctor that does not exist. There is no RandomAccessFile Constructor that just takes a File as an Argument. You need to pass a mode as String as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-

Comment: the code is from one of the links posted as an answer in the other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790224/how-do-i-fetch-specific-bytes-from-a-file-knowing-the-offset-and-length   - the error is a constructor error ???

Comment: do you really need Random Access? maybe a DataInputStream would suffice..and the question of given link is about **fetching a specific byte**, not about reading a word.. and you could use `readInt` instead of `readFully` if you want to read an int

Comment: Thanks for your replys, Yes my question is about both offset and word "Read Data Byte not just Word at offset" anyone know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a word from file directly instead of doing this you can read all data of a file and store it in string buffer and then split it on the basis of space like this

```
String str="Hello my name is saurabh";
           String word[] = str.split(" ");
           for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){
             System.out.println(word[i]);
       }
```